# What's the unit of the scrollbar of loudspeaker?

Tags: audio

I really doubt for a while where I should put this question.

If we click the horn at the lower right corner of the desktop of Windows system, a scrollbar that can control volume will appear, and we can always find a similar object on the panel of a media player:

[image][image][image][image]

I used these scrollbars without doubt everyday, but yesterday a question suddenly came to my mind: what's the unit for these scrollbar? If it's only a percentage, then what's the value and the unit of the value of the maximum? Is there a conversion relationship between the display of the scrollbar and the real volume? (represented by… say… decibel?)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [su]. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you said, all those different sliders are percentage-based...

...which means it is a relation between the actual sound you hear and the source sound.

- Suppose you play an .mp3 that at most has 60dB with the slider at 50%. Therefore the .mp3 would play at 30dB.
- Suppose you play an .mp3 that at most has 120dB with the slider at 50%. Therefore the .mp3 would play at 60dB.

(note that the math might be a little off, as dB is logarithmic in nature, but then again I don't have a source for this feature. Would make sense that they would alter the dB value rather than calculating the actual intensity, anyways I digress here)

There might be, however, some limits based on hardware that prevent sound higher than a given limit to be reproduced. There exists some hardware that actually *amplify* the signal the computer is processing, therefore, at 100%, a sound file can give more or less intense sounds in different computers. And there also exists the matter of speaker amplification.

From source to output, one could think of the following diagram:

> Source file (.wav, .mp3, etc) > Software volume setting > System volume setting > Audio hardware amplification > Speaker amplification > Sound output

As you can see this gives a lot of turns. Let's make this into an example:

- Assume your file has a maximum intensity of **120dB**.
- You hear it in VLC at 50% - So, the sound is now **60dB**.
- The system sound (assuming VLC isn't connected to it) is at 50%. So, the sound is now at **30dB**.
- The sound board (integrated or otherwise) amplifies the sound by 100% (outputted or inputted sound can be amplified electronically in relative or absolute terms, it depends on the board itself). So now the sound is back at **60dB**.
- The speakers amplify the sound 50%. The sound **you hear** is now at a semi-comfortable **90dB**.

(on a personal note, my computer amplifies inputted sound, aka mic sound in absolute terms, at least in Vista. What this does, in comparison to relative amplification, is creating a base signal on which the inputted sound is then added to).

All this is assuming the hardware doesn't cap the signal. If you increase the sound the hardware receives, you can begin to hear a lot more electric noise and the sound will begin to be distorted (akin to [successive remastering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness_war) of records). This is also true for the speakers.

You can see the maximum sound intensity of the audio file using software like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) that can edit the audio files.

Comment: Then is there a way to check the maximum volume of _.mp3_?

Comment: Maybe using a program like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) that allows you to edit almost any sound container out there.

Comment: This answer is not quite right.  The sliders are a percentage of the output, but the volume is adjusted by the output hardware.  The percentage can be modified by software playing the sound as well as amplified speakers.

Comment: @Keltari by adjusted what do you mean? I thought I covered all bases.

Comment: You are right, i just missed some of the answer